# Cannot iterate a list type in python 3

Tags: python, list, loops

Problem:

`root.children`(named in following code) is a `list` type, but I still cannot iterate each item, does anyone know the reason? Thanks!

My code:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, value) -> object:
        self.value = value
        self.children = []
    def __repr__(self, level=0):
        ret = "\t"*level+repr(self.value)+"\n"
        for child in self.children:
            ret += child.__repr__(level+1)
        return ret
    def add_child(self, node):
        self.children.append(node)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.children)
    

list_1 = ['Lisa', 'apple', 'banana']   #, 'orange', 'Kiwi'
root = parent = Node(list_1[0])
i=1
while i < len(list_1):
    current_node = Node(list_1[i])
    parent.add_child(current_node)
    parent = current_node
    j=0
    while j < len(root.children): # root.children is a list type, but I still cannot iterate each item in the list
        print('YES')
        j+=1
    i+=1
print(root)
```

Undesired output:

```
YES
YES
'Lisa'
    'apple'
        'banana'
```

Desired output:

```
YES
YES
YES
YES
YES
'Lisa'
    'apple'
        'banana'
```

My purpose, is actually to search through all items in the current 'root.children', if my target item has already existed in the 'root.children', then I will 'do something'.

Comment: What would this be ```root = parent = Node(list_1[0])```

Comment: Have you tried some [debugging?](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can [step through your program](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) and observe where its behavior diverges from expected behavior. Then work backwards from there to identify the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Pranav, I have debuged, and went through each variables' value, but I just see that when it comes to the root.children, the for loop does not work well, it only happen once, there is \n at the end of each item in the root.children list, I do not know why, that's why I post here

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this with `while` loops instead of `for name in list_1:`?

Comment: You're adding the child to `parent`, but then looping through `root.children`.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, I have many reasons, I have other codes, this part of the code is going to search, wheather my desired item is in the root.children or not, then I will need to 'do domething' if it return true

Comment: @Barmar, because I cannot loop through the 'parent', since the it only holds two values in the while loop, thanks

Comment: You would probably understand what's going on if you did `print('YES', root.children[i].value)`

Comment: @Melina 'I have many reasons', from what we are seeing here, you have many bad reasons. Look into the print proposed by Barmar, and correct the structure of your program. It is hard without knowing what you are trying to achieve to give you feedback on the structure.

Comment: @Mathieu, thanks, yes, I did according to Barmar's suggestion, and 'index out of range', the length of the 'root.children' is always '1', I was wondering why things go like this, as Dhwani has explained, now I see where is the problem.

Comment: My purpose, is actually to search through all items in the current 'root.children', if my target item has already existed in the 'root.children', then I will 'do something'

Comment: How does this work `root = parent = Node(list_1[0])`

Comment: @BuddyBoblll, in it,  I want to initialise the parent with Node class, assign list_1[0] to it, and storage the parent to root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not correct for the desired output. You are expecting the second while loop to run as many times as the number of children root has. But in every iteration root only has one child. All the other subchildren are the children of roots single child and so on.

After the end of the loop this is how your instance root would look like

```
root(
val = "Lisa"
children = [(val="apple",
            children=[(val="banana",children=[])]
           ]
)
```

I hope this made it a little clear. As root has only one child always. The inner loop will run only one time for each time the outer loop runs (which is 2 in your case), so "Yes" is printed only twice

To fix the code and get your desired output you can modify the code and call it recursively instead of using loops. On each recursion call the child of root becomes the root and the function will be called again until you hit your base case, which will be a Node with no children

Comment: Thanks Dhwani, you have exactly understood and described what I want to implement. I am trying the recursive currently according to your suggestion:)